# Simulation of sending FCM message via ADB SHELL on real Xiaomi device does not work

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver, adb, xiaomi

My Firebase service:

```
class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.d("FIREBASE", "Message data payload: ${remoteMessage.data}")
    }
}
```

My simulating:

```
adb shell am broadcast \
    -n com.myproj.proj/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver \
    -a "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" \
    --es "data" "my_data"
```

Answer:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x400000 cmp=com.myproj.proj/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

**On the emulators, this is work properly.**

By debugging on the real device (XIAOMI), I don't get the fcm-message. Why and how can I fix it?